# Postgresql INSERT RETURNING complex type

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have problem with Postgresql functions.
I want to declare a function that will insert one row to the table and than return me this row(but with an fields that are created automatically, like Id).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UserCreate(
    name character varying(80),
    surname character varying(80),
    age int,
    email character varying(80)
)
RETURNS "Users" AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "Users" 
    (name,surname,age,email) VALUES 
    (name, surname,  age, email) RETURNING
    * AS result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

but when i try to create this function i get an error:

```
Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
```

I tryed to find some examples on `RETURNING` clause but all examples were just using basic return types like integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable to ship the results between `insert ... returning` and `return`.  Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UserCreate(
    name character varying(80),
    surname character varying(80),
    age int,
    email character varying(80)
)
RETURNS "Users" AS $$
DECLARE
  result "Users";
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "Users" 
    (name,surname,age,email) 
    VALUES  (name, surname,  age, email) 
    RETURNING * INTO result;
RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: I tried similar solution but it does not work.
I think the problem is that I declare to return one row and the `result` may contain set of rows.
I also tryed `LIMIT 1` but it does not help

Comment: The above works for me and it should work for you. What error message do you get?

Comment: OK, my fault.
I tried to create function with the pgAdmin, but it worked from console.
Will investigate why